# Echo error using if/else in mysqli

Tags: php, error-handling, mysqli, echo

I'm trying to show an error when the user enters an email address that's not found in the system. So far it either echoes on the results page even if the email is in the system along with the other correct echo'd results.

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli(" ", " ", " ", "volsched");

if ($db->connect_errno) {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
          }

$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE volConfirm SET confirmed = "YES" WHERE email = ?');
if (!$mysqli->error) {
   printf("Errormessage: Email not in system %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}

$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT agreename, position, shift_times, confirmed from volConfirm WHERE email = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($agreeName, $position, $shift_times, $confirmed);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
// construct your output here using $row to access database record
echo "<h2>" . $agreeName . "</h2>";
echo "<p> You have been assigned as a volunteer for:" . $position . "</p>";
echo "<p>Your shift times are scheduled for:" . $shift_times . "</p>";
echo "<p>Your shift has been confirmed:" . $confirmed . "</p>";
 }

?>
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. And why do you think "no rows found" would be an error state?

Comment: A: I believe it's all relevant which is why I posted it in Pastebin- it's not that large. B: What?

Comment: You will only receive errors if something is really wrong with your query; otherwise you will get either 0 rows affected or 0 rows returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up using a bit of JS to control what divs are displayed based on whether or not the email address was valid.

```
if($('#returned').length > 0) {
$('.noEmail').hide();
$('#volunteerResults').show()
 }});
```

So if the email address isn't in the system, the .noEmail div which contains "Email not in system" is shown or hidden based on results

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE volConfirm SET confirmed = "YES" WHERE email = ?');


$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT agreeName, position, shift_times, confirmed from volConfirm WHERE email = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
```